# Writing pseudocode for parallel programming

Tags: algorithm2e, sourcecode, pseudocode

"How do you write pseudo-code for parallel programming? Especially, how do you differentiate local and shared variables? How do you represent operations like scatter, gather, reduce, broadcast, and point-to-point communications? Is there some standards about that?"

**Please, note** the original question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583257/writing-pseudocode-for-parallel-programming) but it still does NOT have a good acceptable answer.

**Re-elaborating other questions, summarizing and keeping the things easy**: is there a way of saying in pseudocode "*DO ALL THESE THINGS IN PARALLEL*"?

I am using the package `algorithm2e` with `TeXStudio`. How to typeset the parallel code using them?

Comment: Then I suggest that you elaborate you question, for example explain why the other answers on TeX.SE is not satisfying.

Comment: that is a great suggestion, I will

Comment: the question was updated. I would like to remark that in the original question it was stated that the question is a kind of duplicate of others because there is still a big hole in this field in that direction

Comment: yes it is. To be more precise, how to write it using `algorithm2e`, the package I am using. To be honest, a general answer on how to structure a pseudocode (not only in LaTeX, that I am using right now) can be sufficient

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97185/discussion-between-leos313-and-sveinung).

Comment: I've always regarded peudocode as a way of dumbing down code so that even managers can understand it.  Can you really expect to dumb down parallel code that much?

Comment: I have found a way that just answers to the simple question "ho to say DO THAT IN PARALLEL". It does not solve the original question posted with all the little details of the parallel code. It is a personal solution. I am going to post it as an answer. However, a kind of standard should be tough. And I think that the web community (stackoverflow, StackExchange etc.) should push this kind of development. The pseudocode is not just for managers but to share knowledge (for example on academic papers) on the best strategy to solve problems. Isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some web research, I have realized that a kind of "standard" still does not exits. So here is my personal solution using `algorithm2e`:

```
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
...
\begin{algorithm}
    \DontPrintSemicolon 
    \SetKwBlock{DoParallel}{do in parallel}{end}
    \KwIn{Some inputs}
    \KwOut{The ouput}
    \DoParallel{
        Compute a \;
        Compute b \;
        Compute c \;
    }
    \DoParallel{
        a1\;
        b1\;
        c1\;
    }
    \Return{the solution}\;
    \caption{Parallel Algo}
    \label{algo:parallelAlgorithm}
\end{algorithm}
```

The result is:

[image]

It is based on defining a new command using the expression `\SetKwBlock`. The manual of the package can be found [here](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf).
Also, I have just added almost the same solution to a similar question on StackOverflow. The answer and the question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583257/writing-pseudocode-for-parallel-programming/57415035#57415035).

Using the strategy of defining your keywords in order to describe your algorithm with the details you prefer, it should be always possible. Take into consideration that:

1. more details → more you will be close to your programming languages.
2. fewer details → more it can be seen as a pseudo-code.

> **Concluding**: it is always a matter of trade-offs: you decide where is the limit (taking into account the target people you refer to).

The same strategy has been used in journal papers (for instance, see Algorithm 3 and 4 of [this IEEE journal paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342498175_Exploiting_Multi-Level_Parallelism_for_Run-Time_Adaptive_Inverse_Kinematics_on_Heterogeneous_MPSoCs)).